# Unknown CMake command "add_action_files" during ROS install

Tags: cmake, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing ROS on Mountain Lion (see possible related problems [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/48030/no-cmakeliststxt-in-ros-fuerte-install/)), and I've hit a wall with the following error while using cmake:

```
CMake Error at actionlib/CMakeLists.txt:22 (add_action_files):
Unknown CMake command "add_action_files".
```

In actionlib/CMakeLists.txt, the offending line is:

```
add_action_files(DIRECTORY action FILES Test.action TestRequest.action TwoInts.action)
```

This exists both in the release version of the code both on [github](https://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release) and on [mercurial](https://kforge.ros.org/common/actionlib).

I haven't been able to find the add_action_files command in any of the cmake documentation – I assume it's valid, but I don't know why it's not working! Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48129/unknown-cmake-command-%22add_action_files%22-during-ros-install/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2012-11-12**:
To clarify – I cloned actionlib manually, because the link that gitinstall used was broken. When I go into ros-underlay/common_msgs/actionlib_msgs/cmake/ I have two files – actionbuild.cmake and actionlib_msgs-extras.cmake.in . This last file contains the right macro, but apparently it's not found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed it!

If you experience this error like I did, simply edit your ~/ros-underlay/.rosinstall file and change the actionlib source to git://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git then rerun rosinstall.

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0